# Draw a circle(dot) on an imageview

Tags: android, canvas, paint

I'm trying to write a simple script that, when someone touches a map of the United States, puts a dot on the screen at the (x,y) coordinate.

Code is below.

```
public class map extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView ivMap_ActivityMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        ivMap_ActivityMap = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivMap_ActivityMap);
        ivMap_ActivityMap.setImageResource(R.drawable.usa);
        ivMap_ActivityMap.setOnTouchListener(handleTouch);

    }

    private final View.OnTouchListener handleTouch = new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            int x = (int) event.getX();
            int y = (int) event.getY();
            Toast.makeText(map.this, "x = " + x + ", y = " + y, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Paint paint = new Paint();
            int radius;
            radius = 100;
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            paint.setColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
            canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, paint);

            return true;
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: after drawing the Canvas try using invalidate(); method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code didn't work because you were drawing in an orphan Canvas.

You can achieve your goal by making a canvas with an empty bitmap of the `ImageView` size and after that draw circle and finally set the drawable to the `ImageView` in the following way,

```
public class map extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView ivMap_ActivityMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

        ivMap_ActivityMap = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivMap_ActivityMap);
        // Set the map as background  
        ivMap_ActivityMap.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.usa);
        ivMap_ActivityMap.setOnTouchListener(handleTouch);
}

private final View.OnTouchListener handleTouch = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    // Stored to draw multiple circle. 
    // If you want to draw only one circle then you can make it a local variable
    private Bitmap bmp;

    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        int x = (int) event.getX();
        int y = (int) event.getY();
        Toast.makeText(map.this, "x = " + x + ", y = " + y, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        int radius;
        radius = 100;
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark);
        // Create a bitmap object of your view size
        if(bmp==null) bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
               // Create the canvas with the bitmap
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, paint);
        // Set the bitmap to the imageView
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) v;
               iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        return true;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: If you believe my answer helped then I would request you to perform the operations described in this link, https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Hopefully it will help

```
class DrawingView extends SurfaceView {

        private final SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
        private final Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

        public DrawingView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            surfaceHolder = getHolder();
            paint.setColor(Color.RED);
            paint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if (surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {
                    Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
                    canvas.drawCircle(event.getX(), event.getY(), 5, paint);
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```